# Add route from internal network to external network

Tags: networking, arch-linux, firewall, routing

I am using a box running Arch as my router and firewall (with shorewall). Recently, I tried to add another network onto the system, which failed horribly. After putting everything back where it was before this, and confirming that everything is exactly the same, I am having some issues with routing from my internal network (192.168.1.0/24) to the outside. Here is the current situation:

- I CAN ping the external network from my firewall
- I CAN ping the firewall from my internal network
- I CANNOT ping the external network from the internal network

I have two network interfaces, `enp5s0` (internal) and `enp6s0` (external). Here are my routes from `ip route ls` (note my external ip ends in .78, I redacted the rest for obvious reasons):

```
default via [redacted].1 dev enp6s0  src [redacted].78  metric 203  mtu 576
[redacted].0/24 dev enp6s0  proto kernel  scope link  src [redacted].78
[redacted].0/24 dev enp6s0  proto kernel  scope link  src [redacted].78  metric 203  mtu 576
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp5s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.1  metric 202
```

A traceroute from the machine on the internal network reveals that it gets to 192.168.1.1, then times out. I suspect I need to add another route allowing traffic coming from 192.168.1.0/24 to be routed through enp6s0 out to the net. I've tried different routes, and none have worked.
Also, my dhcpcd.conf did change. If the commented line is uncommented, it creates a second default route which stops any connection at all. Previously, this was not an issue.

```
interface enp5s0
static ip_address=192.168.1.1/24
#static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.1 # I have TOR DNS bound to this ip
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, IP forwarding is enabled.

Comment: Assuming you're using a public IP address on `enp6s0` then you'll need to configure NAT, not IP forwarding.

Comment: @garethTheRed Shorewall should be handling NAT, no?

Comment: It should, if configured correctly...

Comment: @garethTheRed It appears that it's never making it to shorewall. I see nothing in the logs when I try to ping or make an HTTP connection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done something like that on an Arch server.  The server had `enp4s8` as the "external" network, and `wlp1s0` as the "internal" network.  `enp4s8` had a statically-defined IP address of 10.0.0.3, and a default route to 10.0.0.1, the DSL modem.

```
/usr/bin/ip link set dev wlp1s0 up
/usr/bin/ip addr add 172.16.0.1/24 dev wlp1s0
sleep 10

modprobe iptable_nat
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 172.16.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -o enp4s8 -i wlp1s0 -s 172.16.0.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

dhcpd -cf /etc/dhcpd.wlp1s0.conf wlp1s0
```

You may not have IPv4 forwarding turned on, and getting the `iptables` right is sometimes difficult.

The other part of the trick is in `/etc/dhcpd.wlp1s0.conf`.  I think you have to tell machines on the "internal" network about their default route and router with DHCP:

```
option domain-name "fleegle";
option domain-name-servers 172.16.0.1;
option routers 172.16.0.1;
option ntp-servers 10.0.0.3;
default-lease-time 14440;
ddns-update-style none;
deny bootp;
shared-network intranet {
        subnet 172.16.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
                option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
                pool { range 172.16.0.50 172.16.0.200; }
        }
}
```